# Pinescript overlay does not work for buy and sell signals

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create pinescript indicator that has a plot area and also shows buy / sell signals in the actual current graph. Somehow the buy and sell signals get displayed insnide of the indicator graph box. [what did I do wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGNEw.jpg)

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = "LSMA slope", shorttitle="LSMAS", overlay=true)

length = input(title="Length", defval=24)
lsma = ta.linreg(close, length, 0)
one_back_lsma = ta.linreg(close[1], length, 0)
two_back_lsma = ta.linreg(close[2], length, 0)

signal = lsma - one_back_lsma
previous_signal = one_back_lsma - two_back_lsma

p1 = plot(signal, color=signal>=0?color.green:color.red, style=plot.style_area)

longentry = previous_signal < 0 and signal >= 0 or previous_signal <= 0 and signal > 0
shortentry = previous_signal > 0 and signal <= 0 or previous_signal >= 0 and signal < 0

plotshape(longentry, style=shape.triangleup, color=#00FF00,text='BUY', textcolor=#FFFFFF, editable=false, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
plotshape(shortentry, style=shape.triangledown, color=#FF0000, text='SELL', textcolor=#FFFFFF, editable=false, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small)
```

I tried enabling / disabling the overlay=true argument but it didn't change anything. Also note that the version of pinescript is 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the `overlay`, you should remove the indicator from your chart and add it again.

Just to make it clear, you cannot have a plot displayed in a separate window and then plot your Buy/Sell signals in the main chart. An indicator runs only in one window.